# Thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Tags: multithreading, swift, audio

I have built a fully functioning flappy bird game but when I try to add a sound I can't even run the project because an error pops up before I can play the game. the error is:

```
  thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)
```

import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
class GameScene: SKScene {

```
var bird = SKSpriteNode()
var pipeUpTexture = SKTexture()
var pipeDownTexture = SKTexture()
var PipesMoveAndRemove = SKAction()
var sound = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath:    NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("wingsSound", ofType: "waw")!))

let pipeGap = 150.0
```

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

```
    sound!.play()
```

Comment: A better way to play a sound file in SpriteKit is using an SKAction.playSoundFile(soundFile: String, waitForCompletion: bool) also in iOS 9 there is now a SKAudioNode that is built on AVFoundation.

Comment: so how could i then edit my code. thanks?

Comment: Is the sound is wing flying sound correct? I am basing that off the sound file name. If so when do you want that sound to play every time the bird flaps his wings?

Comment: Actually I see an error your sound file is of type "waw" which is incorrect. You either meant to put wav or the avaudioplayer does not support that type of audio file

Comment: i tried to convert the wav* file to mp3 but it still doesn't work